# ValueError: invalid literal for float(): when adding annotation in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, jupyter

I get this error when I try to add an annotation to my plot - `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 10_May`.

my dataframe:

[image]

my code (I use `to_datetime` and `strftime` before ploting as I needed to sort dates which were stored as strings):

```
# dealing with dates as strings
grouped.index = pd.to_datetime(grouped.index, format='%d_%b')
grouped = grouped.sort_index()
grouped.index = grouped.index.strftime('%d_%b')
plt.annotate('Peak',
             (grouped.index[9], grouped['L'][9]),
             xytext=(15, 15), 
             textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))
grouped.plot()
```

`grouped.index[9]` returns `u'10_May'` while `grouped['L'][9]` returns `10.0`.
I know that pandas expect index to be float but I thought I can access it by df.index[]. Will appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me works first plot and then get index position by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.annotate('Peak',
             (df.index.get_loc(df.index[9]), df['L'][9]),
             xytext=(15, 15), 
             textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'L':[3,5,0,1]}, index=['4_May','3_May','1_May', '2_May'])
#print (df)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d_%b')
df = df.sort_index()
df.index = df.index.strftime('%d_%b')
df.plot()
plt.annotate('Peak',
             (df.index.get_loc(df.index[2]), df['L'][2]),
             xytext=(15, 15), 
             textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))
```

[image: graph]

EDIT:

More general solution with [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) + [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) + [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html):

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.annotate('Peak',
             (df.index.get_loc(df['L'].idxmax()), df['L'].max()),
             xytext=(15, 15), 
             textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))
```

Comment: Supeer, nice weekend!